# Best way to reheat pizza

Tags: pizza, reheating

Whats the best way to reheat leftover pizza? We usually use Boboli Crust with our own toppings, or sometimes we have frozen pizza.

Comment: Oh you're missing out -- cold leftover pizza is quite the treat! In fact, I look forward to having leftover pizza just so I can eat it cold the next day.

Answer (score 15):

@Cos is right, a pizza stone is great - so is a pizza screen in the oven.

If I don't want to heat up the oven (big oven, little piece of pizza aways seems like a waste), then a cast iron pan over medium heat on the stove with a lid does pretty well.

Comment: definitely like this idea for small jobs (1-2 pieces)

Answer (score 8):

I have always had the most satisfactory results from preheating the oven to 400F with a pizza stone and then setting the cold pizza on the hot stone for 8 to 10 minutes?

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to reheat a slice or two, you can warm it in the microwave for 30 seconds to a minute and then put it in a toaster oven on toast or a hot oven setting for a few minutes. It's best in the toaster oven if you put the slice(s) on the broiling rack on top of the baking sheet.

Comment: I'm going to heartily recommend *against* the microwave. Seems to make the crust chewy.

Comment: @philosodad: the toaster oven more or less cancels out the chewiness that the microwave would add. The microwave/toaster oven approach is definitely about balancing convenience with quality. The toaster oven alone gives a somewhat better overall result but takes longer.

Comment: @amcnabb You are right. The combo of both the toaster oven and the microwave is key (microwave alone means it comes out chewy and soggy, toaster alone is either burnt or not heated all the way through) - together the microwave quickly warms it and the toaster oven undoes the sogginess created by the microwave - making it golden brown and delicious.

Answer (score 4):

Since I prefer thin crust pizzas, oven re-heating often results in something resembling a burnt cracker with some half-cold toppings on it.

To avoid this, I "fry" leftover pizza to reheat it: I place a tiny bit of oil or butter into the bottom of a non-stick skillet, add slices of pizza, cover, and place over very low heat until the cheese is re-melted.

This method allows the pizza to warm and steam gently, while also ever-so-slightly frying the bottom of the crust, so one ends up with something very near the consistency of a fresh slice rather than a dried-out, inconsistently-warmed leftover.

This technique works with everything from thin crust to deep-dish pizza; only the reheating times are different.

Answer (score 2):

I like to put a heavy sheet pan in the oven and preheat it to 350°F. Then I just slide my leftover slices onto the hot pan and bake for 5 minutes. The hot pan crisps up the bottom of the crust and the hot oven does the rest. Does a nice job of bringing a good slice of pizza back to life.

Answer (score 1):

I found that a short burst in the microwave heats up up the whole piece. Then, you have to  immediately put it into a very hot oven to get it crispy on the outside. (You said "the best way", not the most energy efficient.)

Answer (score 0):

I use an oven at 250°F for a longer period of time--usually about 15 minutes, with the pizza either in or on tin foil. This seems to work well, it heats the pizza but doesn't toast the crust.

Comment: I hope you mean 250 F, not C.

Answer (score 0):

Pizza stone on 350 for 10 minutes. Or if your lazy and don't own a pizza stone, like me, toaster oven on toast for however long it takes too heat, crisp up and not burn.

Comment: Welcome to the site! It seems your answer doesn't contain a new suggestion - if you agree with what others wrote, you would upvote their answer(s), not repeat it. On the other hand, if you can *explain* in your answer *why* your approach is the best, it might be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

With a waffle iron!!! 
[Leftover Pizza + Waffle Iron = Delicious Crispy, Gooey, Cheese-Stuffed Snack](http://slice.seriouseats.com/archives/2014/01/leftover-pizza-waffle-iron-delicious-crispy-gooey-cheese-stuffed-snack.html)

Answer (score 0):

For larger amounts of leftover frozen thin crust pizza- Line a medium/large baking pan/sheet that has at least 1/4 inch vertical sides on it with tin foil. Use middle rack. If two baking pans are used, use rack positions 1 and 4. 1 being the lowest rack, 4 being the higher one. Preheat oven on *Convection/Bake* at 425F to 450F. After preheating oven,  place frozen thin crust pizza on baking pan/s. Put pan/s in oven and heat for approx 30 minutes. Check at 20 minutes to make sure not to over cook. Enjoy!